# Large number of Quartz worker threads

Tags: java, multithreading, quartz-scheduler

I am using Quartz 2.1.16

I have a scheduler with 2 jobs. Job 1 runs every 15 minutes and Job 2 runs once a day. And I am with DefaultQuartzScheduler. At the end of the day, if I check my application I am left with 70 quartz threads in TIMED WAITING state. Below is the dump. It is just a part of the dump. There are a total of 70 threads. The thread count will ultimately force me to restart the server. Any idea what's going on with my scheduler?

```
"DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-8" Id=4367 in TIMED_WAITING on lock=org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread@706a706a (running in native)
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:196)
      at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:552)

"DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-9" Id=4368 in TIMED_WAITING on lock=org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread@71147114 (running in native)
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:196)
      at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:552)

 "DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-10" Id=4369 in TIMED_WAITING on lock=org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread@71be71be (running in native)
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:196)
      at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:552)

 "DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread" Id=4370 in TIMED_WAITING on lock=java.lang.Object@708e708e (running in native)
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:196)
      at org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:437)
```

Comment: are you doing a wait call somewhere in the job execute

Comment: Look at his stack trace--there is only quartz in there.  I'm having a similar problem.

Comment: What thread-pool configuration do you use for your Quartz instance?

Comment: please post your quartz configs and code.

Comment: @sadhu are you able to figure out this issue

Comment: @TechSavvy No. We moved ahead with OS schedulers

Comment: Please post your code